# “%%” on a vector with non-numeric and numeric values

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I have a Feature Vector **fv** with Numeric and Non-numeric features

```
fv <- c(22, 72, "San Jose", 60)
```

I need to replace values that are divisible by 3 with a String

```
fv[fv%%3==0] <- "Negligible"
```

However I get the following error message:

```
Error in fv%%3 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Due to the **"San Jose"** Feature in the Feature Vector.

How can I ignore the non-numerics in

```
fv[fv%%3==0] <- "Negligible"
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fv[as.numeric(fv)%%3==0] <- "Negligible"
#[1] "22"         "Negligible" "San Jose"   "Negligible"
```

A warning will be triggered which is OK due to `NA` introduced by the string in the vector.